# How do I install an HDD caddy in the optical bay of a Dell Studio 1745?

Tags: hard-drive

I want to order the 2nd hdd caddy for my laptop, like this: http://www.qkyparts.co.uk/dell-studio-1745-2nd-hdd-hard-drive-caddy.html

[image: optical bay hdd caddy]

How do I install this caddy once I've received it?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill, he's not asking for a product reccomendation.  He's asking for a how-to video for a product he's already decided to purchase.

Comment: @WesSayeed A **how to** video (aka tutorial video) seems to me to fit in the category of **learning material** ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had one on a different laptop, but it's the same concept. Here is how you do it:

1. Install the hard drive into the device by screwing it into the caddy.
2. Remove the optical drive (CD/DVD drive) from your laptop. It is usually held in by a single screw on the bottom of your laptop. It may take a little trial and error to find out which screw hold it in, but it's almost never more than one screw.
3. Push the caddy into the same exact slot where the optical drive went. As long as it is compatible with your laptop, it will slide right in.
4. Now just screw in the same screw in the same place where the optical drive screw went.
5. In a few seconds, the new hard drive should show up in windows. Usually you will not even need to reboot. No drivers are necessary, in most cases.

Voila! More hard drive space!

p.s. For some of these caddys, you may need to remove the end piece located on the optical drive which is usually held on by two screws to the optical drive, which is what the screw on the bottom of the laptop goes through in order to hold in the optical drive. Simply relocate this small piece off of the optical drive and onto the caddy in the same location and screw it on with the same little screws.

This should work for you. Let me know if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of articles on the Super User Blog that I wrote about this subject. You may find them helpful.

- [About optical bay caddies and how to select one](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/04/best-of-both-worlds-putting-an-ssd-in-your-optical-bay/)
- [The installation process](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/30/installing-the-optical-bay-hdd/)

It's fairly simple. Consult your computer's service manual for instructions on how to remove the optical drive, then just swap it out with the new HDD caddy.